# how to connect two nodes for react-flow-renders testing in cypress

Tags: cypress

```js
it("search source input and drag and drop the souce input",() => {
        const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
        cy.get('[data-nodeid="targetPathInput"]')
          .trigger("mousedown", { dataTransfer} ).wait(1000);
        cy.get('[data-handleid="0"]')
          .trigger("mouseup,"  dataTransfer});
});
```

***Its not working for me mousedown and mouseup***

Answer (score 0):

```
its("search for source input and drag and drop the source input", () => {
cy.get('sourceInputId'). trigger ("mousemove");
cy.get('sourceInputId'). trigger ("mousedown");
cy.get('targetInputId'). trigger ("mousemove");
cy.get('targetInputId'). trigger ("mouseup");
    })
```

***it's worked for me in many websites.***

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).